# Why can a not null variable plus a null value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following code can be compiled in Android Studio.

I'm very strange why a  not null variable can plus a null value.

1: You know `val s` maybe null and  `var userData` is not null, why is  `userData = userData + s` correct?

2:  What  is the result of  `userData = userData + null` ?  will the App crash when it run?

```
 var userData: String by remember { mutableStateOf("OK") }
 userData = userData + null

 val s = it.message?.content     
 userData = userData + s
```

Comment: The [`plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/plus.html) operator function defined for `String` accepts an `Any?` (i.e., a nullable type). In your case, `userData = userData + null` should result in `"OKnull"`.

Comment: @Slaw Post an answer and claim the bounty. That looks like as reputable a source as any IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at the following two examples:

1. `val a = "a" + null // a is String "anull"`
2. `val b = null + "b" // b is String "nullb"`

To understand what's happening, we need to know how the `+` works in each case.

In Case 1: the operator being used is `operator fun String.plus(other: Any?): String` ([this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/plus.html))

> Returns a string obtained by concatenating this string with the string representation of the given other object.

The "string representation" of `null` is the string `"null"`. Therefore this is just concatenating the two strings `"a"` and `"null"`.

In Case 2: the operator being used is `operator fun String?.plus(other: Any?): String` ([this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/plus.html))

> Concatenates this string with the string representation of the given other object. If either the receiver or the other object are null, they are represented as the string "null".

Hence, similarly, this is equivalent to concatenating strings `"null"` and `"b"`.